# Use of matrix multiplication function in TensorFlow

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow

I am a bit confused about the use of the function `tf.matmul()` in TensorFlow. My question might be more about the theory of deep learning, though. Say you have an input X and weight matrix W (assuming zero bias), I want to compute WX as an output which could be done by `tf.matmul(W, X)`. However, in the tutorial [MNIST for beginners](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html#mnist-for-ml-beginners) it is reversed and `tf.matmul(X, W)` is used instead. On the other hand, in the next tutorial [TensorFlow Mechanics 101](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/mnist/tf/index.html#tensorflow-mechanics-101), `tf.matmul(W, X)` is used. Since the matrix sizes are important for multiplication I wonder if someone can clarify this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know much about TensorFlow, but intuitively I feel that the confusion is regarding the data representation of input. When you say you want to multiply an input `X` with a weight `W` I think what you mean is that you want to multiply each dimension (feature) with its corresponding weight and take the sum. So if you have an input `x` with say `m` dimensions, you should have a weight vector `w` with `m` values (`m+1` if you consider the bias).

Now if you choose to represent the different training instances as rows of a matrix `X`, you would have to perform `X * w`, instead if you choose to represent them as columns, you would do `w^T * X`

Comment: If you want multiple training instances in a batch, you need to use `tf.batch_matmul`, which internally treats the first dimension as a batch dimension.  Remember that weights can be a matrix, not a vector:  You may produce multiple outputs based upon different weights of the input features.  I've updated my answer to point this out.

Comment: Thanks @jMathew. I think you are right. I was assuming that the input should be represented as (n_Features x n_Samples) but it seems to be the other way around in most of the examples. dga, it has nothing to do with whether or not W is a vector or we are feeding bathces.

Answer (score 5):

I think you must be misreading the mechanics 101 tutorial - or could you point to the specific line?

In general, for a network layer, I think of the inputs "flowing through" the weights.  To represent that, I write `tf.matmul(Inputs, Weights)` to produce the output of that layer.  That output may then have a bias `b` added to it, and the result of that fed into a nonlinear function such as a relu, and then into another `tf.matmul` as the input for the next layer.

Second, remember that the Weights matrix may be sized to produce multiple outputs.  That's why it's a matrix, not just a vector.  For example, if you wanted two hidden units and you had five input features, you would use a shape `[5, 2]` weight matrix, like this (shown in numpy for ease of exposition - you can do the same thing in tensorflow):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
W = np.array([[.5, .6], [.7, .8], [.9, .1], [.2, .3], [.4, .5]])

>>> np.dot(a, W)
array([ 7.4,  6.2])
```

This has the nice behavior that if you then add a batch dimension to `a`, it still works:
    a = np.array[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                 [6, 7, 8, 9, 0]]

```
>>> np.dot(a, W)
array([[  7.4,   6.2],
       [ 20.9,  17.7]])
```

This is exactly what you're doing when you use tf.matmul to go from input features to hidden units, or from one layer of hidden units to another.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am still confused. We need to compute Weights * Inputs so why not tf.matmul(Weights, Inputs)? tf.matmul(a, W) produces a * W instead of W * a.

Comment: I think of it this way:  Imagine you have 5 activations coming in to your weight matrix, and you want there to be 2 outputs from this computation.  Your "input size" to the layer is 5, and your "output" size from the layer is 2.  Further, you have a batch size B.  I find a natural representation of this is that your input is `[B, 5]` with the first dimension being the batch.  If you set up your weight matrix as a `[5x2]` matrix, then you can multiply any batch size in:  `[B x 5] * [5 x 2] --> [B, 2]`.

You could, of course, transpose both matrices and multiply `W_t*a_t`.

Comment: Unfortunately as discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34908326/281545 np.dot does not match tf.matmul semantics - in particular both operands must be matrices. Any workarounds ?

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating more on the answer given by @jMathew.

It all depends on how you represent your feature vector `x`

1. Representation such that rows = instances and columns = features:

Here, let's consider the dimension of `x` is `m x n` then we have `m` instances and `n` features. For this, the weight vector `w` would be of the shape `n x z` where `z` is the number of neurons in that layer. To multiply `x` and `w` we have to do `x * W` so that the shapes of the 2 vectors match for a legal matrix multiplication operation to happen.

2. Representation such that rows = features and columns = instances:

Here, we will have to do `W^T * x` inorder to ensure that the shapes of the 2 vectors match for a legal matrix multiplication operation to happen.