# ValueError when performing matmul with Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm a total beginner to TensorFlow, and I'm trying to multiply two matrices together, but I keep getting an exception that says:

```py
ValueError: Shapes TensorShape([Dimension(2)]) and TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(None)]) must have the same rank
```

Here's minimal example code:

```py
data = np.array([0.1, 0.2])
x = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[2])
T1 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([2,2]))
l1 = tf.matmul(T1, x)
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    sess.run(feed_dict={x: data}
```

Confusingly, the following very similar code works fine:

```py
data = np.array([0.1, 0.2])
x = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[2])
T1 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([2,2]))
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    sess.run(T1*x, feed_dict={x: data}
```

Can anyone point to what the issue is? I must be missing something obvious here..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [`tf.matmul()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/matmul) op requires that both of its inputs are matrices (i.e. 2-D tensors)<sup>*</sup>, and doesn't perform any automatic conversion. Your `T1` variable is a matrix, but your `x` placeholder is a length-2 vector (i.e. a 1-D tensor), which is the source of the error.

By contrast, the `*` operator (an alias for [`tf.multiply()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/multiply)) is a broadcasting element-wise multiplication. It will convert the vector argument to a matrix by following [NumPy broadcasting rules](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

To make your matrix multiplication work, you can either require that `x` is a matrix:

```
data = np.array([[0.1], [0.2]])
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[2, 1])
T1 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([2, 2]))
l1 = tf.matmul(T1, x)
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    sess.run(l1, feed_dict={x: data})
```

...or you could use the [`tf.expand_dims()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims) op to convert the vector to a matrix:

```
data = np.array([0.1, 0.2])
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[2])
T1 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([2, 2]))
l1 = tf.matmul(T1, tf.expand_dims(x, 1))
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # ...
```

<sup>*</sup> This was true when I posted the answer at first, but now `tf.matmul()` also supports batched matrix multiplications. This requires both arguments to have *at least* 2 dimensions. See [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/matmul) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, perfect! That error message was pretty cryptic.

Comment: That's a good point! I'll send in a patch to improve it in the next version.

Comment: Thanks - so is it possible to multiply a vector with a matrix to get a vector (not a matrix)? Or do I have to follow this answer and then reshape ?

Comment: Now tf.mul became tf.multiply

Comment: @ToussaintLouverture Thanks, I've updated the links.

Comment: Good suggestion. But you are missing  `sess.run(l1, feed_dict={x: data}) }`. Though it is small thing, but for beginners' level it may be helpful .

Comment: @Shyamkkhadka Good point: I copied that from the question, and didn't notice that it wasn't valid code. Updated the answer per your suggestion.