# How can I multiply a vector and a matrix in tensorflow without reshaping?

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix-multiplication

This:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 1])
w = np.array([[.5, .6], [.7, .8], [.7, .8]])

print(np.dot(a, w))
# [ 2.6  3. ] # plain nice old matrix multiplication n x (n, m) -> m

import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant(a, dtype=tf.float64)
w = tf.constant(w)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(tf.matmul(a, w).eval())
```

results in:

```
C:\_\Python35\python.exe C:/Users/MrD/.PyCharm2017.1/config/scratches/scratch_31.py
[ 2.6  3. ]
# bunch of errors in windows...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\_\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\common_shapes.py", line 671, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
    input_tensors_as_shapes, status)
  File "C:\_\Python35\lib\contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "C:\_\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 1 for 'MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [3], [3,2].

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/MrD/.PyCharm2017.1/config/scratches/scratch_31.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(tf.matmul(a, w).eval())
  File "C:\_\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py", line 1765, in matmul
    a, b, transpose_a=transpose_a, transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
  File "C:\_\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py", line 1454, in _mat_mul
    transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
  File "C:\_\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 763, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\_\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2329, in create_op
    set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)
  File "C:\_\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1717, in set_shapes_for_outputs
    shapes = shape_func(op)
  File "C:\_\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1667, in call_with_requiring
    return call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn=True)
  File "C:\_\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\common_shapes.py", line 610, in call_cpp_shape_fn
    debug_python_shape_fn, require_shape_fn)
  File "C:\_\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\common_shapes.py", line 676, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
    raise ValueError(err.message)
ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 1 for 'MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [3], [3,2].

Process finished with exit code 1
```

(not sure why the same exception is raised inside its handling)

The solution suggested in  [Tensorflow exception with matmul](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34908326/281545) is reshaping the vector to a matrix but this leads to needlessly complicated code - is there still no other way to multiply a vector with a matrix?

Incidentally using `expand_dims` (as suggested in the link above) with default arguments raises a `ValueError` - that's not mentioned in the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims) and defeats the purpose of having a default argument.

Comment: Accepted answer works but that's really an API bug - reported: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9055

Comment: Thanks for making an issue, this behavior bothered me as well. For much nicer solution to this and more use cases see my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Matmul was coded for rank two or greater tensors.  Not sure why to be honest as numpy has it such that it allows for matrix vector multiplication as well.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 1])
w = np.array([[.5, .6], [.7, .8], [.7, .8]])

print(np.dot(a, w))
# [ 2.6  3. ] # plain nice old matix multiplication n x (n, m) -> m
print(np.sum(np.expand_dims(a, -1) * w , axis=0))
# equivalent result [2.6, 3]

import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant(a, dtype=tf.float64)
w = tf.constant(w)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  # they all produce the same result as numpy above
  print(tf.matmul(tf.expand_dims(a,0), w).eval())
  print((tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(tf.expand_dims(a,-1), w), axis=0)).eval())
  print((tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(a, tf.transpose(w)), axis=1)).eval())

  # Note tf.multiply is equivalent to "*"
  print((tf.reduce_sum(tf.expand_dims(a,-1) * w, axis=0)).eval())
  print((tf.reduce_sum(a * tf.transpose(w), axis=1)).eval())
```

Comment: Oh thanks - well, it's not matrix multiplication then ;) Are those 2 equivalent ? Could you explain a bit what reduce sum does ? Sorry too much fighting with tf today, I 'm dizzy

Comment: So the "*" multiplication operation supports regular numpy broadcasting sematics(it might be missing some fancy indexing stuff). In the above it will multiply a the vector across each vector in w.  Then reduce_sum will collapse a dimension by summing along that dimension. so we go from  a * w -> reduce_sum(product) -> ans;  ([n * nxm]) -> [nxm] -> [m].  Axis determines which axis to add over in this case we want 0 to get our final result of dimension m.

Comment: Nope I'm sorry -> `print(tf.reduce_sum(a * w, axis=0).eval())` results in `ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 3 and 2 for 'mul' (op: 'Mul') with input shapes: [3], [3,2].` in code in question

Comment: Sorry about the mixup in broadcasting.  I've fixed the code and provided both examples that produce the same results in numpy and tf.

Comment: Thanks - I reported it here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9055

Answer (score 14):

[`tf.einsum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/einsum) gives you the ability to do exactly what you need in concise and intuitive form:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(tf.einsum('n,nm->m', a, w).eval())
    # [ 2.6  3. ]
```

You even get to write your comment explicitly `n x (n, m) -> m`. It is more readable and intuitive in my opinion.

My favorite use case is when you want to multiply a batch of matrices with a weight vector:

```
n_in = 10
n_step = 6
input = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, n_step, n_in))
weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal((n_in, 1), stddev=1.0/np.sqrt(n_in)))
Y_predict = tf.einsum('ijk,kl->ijl', input, weights)
print(Y_predict.get_shape())
# (?, 6, 1)
```

So you can easily multiply weights over all batches with no transformations or duplication. This you can not do by expanding dimensions like in other answer. So you avoid the [`tf.matmul`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/matmul) requirement to have matching dimensions for batch and other outer dimensions:

> The inputs must, following any transpositions, be tensors of rank >= 2 where the inner 2 dimensions specify valid matrix multiplication arguments, and any further outer dimensions match.

Comment: Thanks didn't know about einsum

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`tf.tensordot`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensordot) and set `axes=1`. For the simple operation of a vector times a matrix, this is a bit cleaner than [`tf.einsum`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46338763/249341)

```
tf.tensordot(a, w, 1)
```