# tf.matmul(X,weight) vs tf.matmul(X,tf.traspose(weight)) in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, glove

In standard ANN for fully connected layers we are using the following formula: `tf.matmul(X,weight) + bias`. Which is clear to me, as we use matrix multiplication in order to connect input with th hidden layer.

But in GloVe implementation(https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/) we are using the following formula for embeddings multiplication: `tf.matmul(W, tf.transpose(U))` what confuses me is `tf.transpose(U)`part.
Why do we use `tf.matmul(W, tf.transpose(U))` instead of `tf.matmul(W, U)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with the choice of column vs row orientation for the vectors.

Note that `weight` is the second parameter here:

```
tf.matmul(X, weight)
```

But the first parameter, `W`, here:

```
tf.matmul(W, tf.transpose(U))
```

So what you are seeing is a practical application of the following matrix transpose identity:

[image: matrix multiplication transpose identity]

---

To bring it back to your example, let's assume 10 inputs and 20 outputs.

The first approach uses row vectors. A single input `X` would be a `1x10` matrix, called a row vector because it has a single row. To match, the `weight` matrix needs to be `10x20` to produce an output of size `20`.

But in the second approach the multiplication is reversed. That is a hint that everything is using column vectors. If the multiplication is reversed, then everything gets a transpose. So this example is using column vectors, so named because they have a single column.

That's why the transpose is there. The way they GLoVe authors have done their notation, with the multiplication reversed, the weight matrix `W` must already be transposed to `20x10` instead of `10x20`. And they must be expecting a `20x1` column vector for the output.

So if the input vector `U` is naturally a `1x10` row vector, it also has to be transposed, to a `10x1` column vector, to fit in with everything else.

---

Basically you should pick row vectors or column vectors, all the time, and then the order of multiplications and the transposition of the weights is determined for you.

Personally I think that column vectors, as used by GloVe, are awkward and unnatural compared to row vectors. It's better to have the multiplication ordering follow the data flow ordering.

Comment: I found these answers to be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/a/34305091/8553795; https://stackoverflow.com/a/76121153/8553795